# how do I correctly import tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

`import tensorflow as tf`

I get this message in Anaconda interpreter... can somebody help?

Thanks!

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? How did you install the package, what other packages do you have, etc.

Comment: I saw your other post, are you using the base environment for development??

Comment: I just uninstalled anaconda and installed everything again in its last version and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the base environment for everything this time?

Comment: Yes I was using always the base environment. The problem was that some packets were not updated, I guess. Tensorflow works now, even though it is reporting a big warning:

 C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\MIGUEL\anaconda3\lib\sit bla bla bla

Comment: _Yes I was using always the base environment._ Are you still doing it now, though?

Comment: yes I am still using the base environment. Seems to work ok

Comment: Don’t. Nothing good can come from it, and it defeats the point of using virtual environments.... Especially considering how easy it is to create environments, I see no reason not to.

Comment: What do you mean nothing good can come from it?

Comment: Hi it was finally solved by using a tensorflow environment. The base environment leads to problems when importing tensorflow and its libraries.

Comment: _The base environment leads to problems when importing tensorflow and its libraries._ Using the base environment will lead to issues for all kinds of libraries lol, that's the point I was trying to make in my previous comments. Again, don't touch the base environment, if you have then reset the environment or reinstall Conda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the Answer in this (Answer) section even though it is present in the Comments section for the benefit of the community.

Issue is resolved by Installing `Tensorflow` in a `New Virtual Environment`.

Using Virtual Environments has advantages like

- We can maintain multiple versions of `Tensorflow` in multiple `Virtual Environments` with each `Virtual Environment` comprising each version like `1.14, 1.15, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2,etc..`
- We can use different `Python Versions` (`2.x, 3.6, 3.7`) in each `Virtual Environment`
- If we want to modify the `source code` of any of the `Tensorflow API`, we can do it within our `Virtual Environment`, without impacting its functionality in other `Virtual Environments`.

Steps for Creating a New `Virtual Environment` and installing `Tensorflow` in `Anaconda`, for different Operating Systems, is shown below:

```
# Create a New Virtual Environment
conda create --name TF_2_VE

# When conda asks you to proceed, type y:
proceed ([y]/n)?

# Activate the Virtual Environment. Conda Version > 4.6 
conda activate TF_2_VE

# Activating Virtual Environment, Conda Version < 4.6 and Windows OS
activate TF_2_VE

# Activating Virtual Environment, Conda Version < 4.6 and Linux and Mac OS
source activate TF_2_VE


# Install the TF Version you need
conda install tensorflow
```

Hope this information helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: This answer is specific for linux while OP is using windows

Comment: Updated the Answer and made it more generic for different Operating Systems. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Why install TensorFlow using, pip instead of Conda??

Comment: @AMC, Replaced `pip install tensorflow==2.1` with `conda install tensorflow==2.1`.

Comment: Why version 2.1? Is that what OP was trying to install?

Comment: @AMC, I thought if we don't specify the version, it will install Nightly version. But I checked it and that is not the case. Removed the version from the answer. Thank you for  the feedback.

Comment: This is what I did in an ubuntu OS: https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084

Answer (score 0):

To install the current release of CPU-only TensorFlow, recommended for beginners:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

if you already have cuda software

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

Comment: There is no need to install CUDA-software anymore, a conda install tensorflow-gpu comes with a pre-packed version of the CUDA toolkit and CUDNN Which resides in the specific environment (See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533291/is-it-still-necessary-to-install-cuda-before-using-the-conda-tensorflow-gpu-pack)