# Which Cuda Version do i have? Strange behavior of Conda virtual env

Tags: cuda, conda

I always thought i have:

Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
as determined by:

```
nvcc --version
```

However

```
conda info list
```

prints:

```
   virtual packages : __cuda=10.2
                      __glibc=2.27
```

Next, i checked:

```
nvidia-smi

NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      
Driver Version: 440.100      
CUDA Version: 10.2
```

In case i have indeed:
release 10.0, V10.0.130

How can i change the virtual environment for conda?
Or do i have two versions installed (by mistake)?

(all on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61533291/681865

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53422407/681865

Comment: It is possible to have more than one CUDA version installed, and in factyou evidently have more than one version installed.  anaconda installs a subset of the usual CUDA toolkit, in separate locations of its choosing.   So you appear to have a conda-subset of 10.2.  You also appear to have an ordinary CUDA install of 10.0.  The version reported by `nvidia-smi` is not actually the installed CUDA toolkit version but the installed CUDA driver version (the GPU driver version is 440.100, the CUDA driver version is 10.2).

Comment: Thanks! How can i tell conda to use the ordinary CUDA 10.0 install. The 10.2 install was likely triggered as unwanted security update (and removing it might cause other trouble).