# Difference between nvidia/cuda-toolkit and nvidia/cudatoolkit packages

Tags: installation, conda, nvidia

Looking in the `nvidia` channel on Conda, I see two different packages [cuda-toolkit](https://anaconda.org/nvidia/cuda-toolkit) and [cudatoolkit](https://anaconda.org/nvidia/cudatoolkit).

The [official CUDA Toolkit documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#conda-installation) refers to the [cuda](https://anaconda.org/nvidia/cuda) package. Installing this installs the `cuda-toolkit` package.

But other packages like `cudnn` and `tensorflow-gpu` depend on `cudatoolkit`. Even if I have followed the official CUDA Toolkit guide to install it, and the `cuda-toolkit` is installed, these other packages still install `cudatoolkit` as a dependency.

So I really want to understand the difference between `cudatoolkit` and `cuda-toolkit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have figured it out. Thanks in part to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61538568/4801767).

`cudatoolkit` is a barebones package with the most essential libraries that other packages typically need. This is **not** the actual CUDA Toolkit. Hence, many software packages install this as a dependency. Because it is small and stable.

`cuda-toolkit` on the other hand, is the more comprehensive package that is installed as part of installing the complete CUDA Toolkit.